# RavenDB DeleteByIndex

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am working on a web crawler and the results which are saved to Raven can vary on how big the website is. I'm trying to delete a specific result which has over the the "server per session is limited to 30", I don't want to extend it to the 1,000 limit, I do however want to batch delete.

The code I have written which I think should work is

```
    public void DeleteCrawledLinks(string baseUrl)
    {

        DocumentStore().DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(
            "Auto/UrlContainers/ByBaseUrlAndUrl",
            new IndexQuery
            {
                Query = "BaseUrl:" + baseUrl // where BaseUrl contains baseUrl
            }, allowStale: false);
     }
```

the BaseUrl in Raven for this example let's call it "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:2125/" and the baseUrl will be the same, when I run the delete function I get this error message

Url: "/bulk_docs/Auto/UrlContainers/ByBaseUrlAndUrl?query=BaseUrl%253Ahttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A2125%252F&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None&allowStale=False"

System.ArgumentException: The field 'http' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed

Is it because of the : in my query, is there a way around this or is there another way? I don't want to extend the limit because the sites I crawl could have more than 1,000 results returned.

Comment: The query you are sending is syntactically invalid because of the ":" in baseUrl.

Comment: What happens if you url encode baseUrl?

Comment: UrlEncode stops the error, but it doesn't appear to match because it doesn't delete, I could be missing something else but I'm not sure, still quite new to NOSQL

Comment: Try either putting quotes around the term, or escaping `:` with `\:`.  Can't recall which way it is here.  It's either `"BaseUrl:\"" + baseUrl + "\""`  or `"BaseUrl:" + baseUrl.Replace(":","\:")`

Comment: "BaseUrl:" + baseUrl.Replace(":","\\:")  worked perfectly, put it into an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, use RavenQuery.Escape() instead.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll implement it when I get back into work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing the query yourself, escape search terms as follows:

```
Query = "BaseUrl:" + RavenQuery.Escape(baseUrl)
```

Comment: Isn't there a proper replace helper method instead of this ad-hoc and buggy way?